# How show two images in a figure

Tags: matlab

I need to show two 3D images using one figure, I used alpha( 0.5) but i have problem with colormap
This is my code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% liver 1 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
liver_surf1=isosurface(nii.img(:,end:-1:1,:),0.05);
V=liver_surf1.vertices;
F=liver_surf1.faces;
t=trisurf(F,V(:,1),V(:,2),V(:,3),'facealpha',0.5,'FaceColor',colormap([1 0 0])); % red color
shading flat;
hold on;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% liver 2 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
liver_surf=isosurface(nii.img(:,end:-1:1,end:-1:1),0.05);
V2=liver_surf.vertices;
F2=liver_surf.faces;
t2 = trisurf(F2,V2(:,1),V2(:,2),V2(:,3),'facealpha',0.5,'FaceColor',colormap([0 1 0])); % green color
```

and this is result :
[image]

Then problem is that both images colors change to green, if i run separately is ok but i cannot combine both images together. so after i add "shading flat" it becomes like this :

[image]

how can i have red and green color together ? 
thanks

these are two different liver which should show in an image with transparency because they have intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that code even works (what version of MATLAB do you have?), I would expect `trisurf` to error. Anyway, `colormap` is a function that sets the colormap of the image, not of the individual surfaces. You set the colormap to green, all the things will be green.

What you want is to set the colordata, `C`, to a single value of the same size of your z, then adjust the colormap to give you the right colors.  Here's an easy way:

```
trisurf(F,V(:,1),V(:,2),V(:,3),zeros(size(V(:,3))));  % Cdata = 0
trisurf(F2,V2(:,1),V2(:,2),V2(:,3),,ones(size(V2(:,3)))); %Cdata = 1
colormap([1 0 0; 0 1 0]);
```

This basically makes two surfaces, one with all color values at zero, the other with all color values at one.  The `colormap` call changes the colormap so it only has two values red (zero) and green (one).  (Should also work if you add facealpha etc).

[image]